# AMPscript LookupRows Function Not Working

Tags: lookup, marketing-cloud

I am using a Landing page to display the desired row from the Triggered sends using the LOOKUPROWS function. As below

```
%%[ 
VAR @Rows
SET @Rows = LOOKUPROWS("abandon_cart","firstName","XYZ")
]%%

Details :%%= v(@Rows )=%%
```

but in browser the result I see is -  **Details :System.Data.DataRow[]** 
Am I missing something in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOOKUPROWS is returning you a rowset.  You are going to need to get a specific row using ROW() and then get the field using FIELD instead of just the v() operator, like so:

```
 Details = %%=FIELD(ROW(@Rows,1), "firstName") =%%
```

Comment: Here are some additional examples: http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Comment: @Timothy..is it possible to display the complete row with all the values on web page?